# wp_set_object_terms( $vid, '0', 'priorities'); does not update (initiate) the taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

In the statement `wp_set_object_terms( $vid, '0', 'priorities');`, `$vid` is the item id to bind with the tax `priorities` and initiate with the value `0`.
It was working for more than two years until yesterday.
Replacing the `'0'` with `'1'` works well.
A workaround is to replace the `'0'` with `' 0 '`.
Can anyone explain and solve this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this change](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/256272e534f4085a419a56eed5e80ecb435432b1), in version 6.3 WordPress was updated to support emptying the terms assigned to a post by passing an empty value in a way that won't cause an error in PHP 8.1+. PHP treats '0' as empty, so your code is treated as setting no terms on the post.

If you want the previous behaviour you should pass an array with `'0'` as the only value:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $vid, array( '0' ), 'priorities');
```